# Put URL as variable in a fetch in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, url, environment-variables, fetch, concatenation

I want to pass an URL in a fetch as a variable or concatenation.

When I put my URL as a string it works : `fetch('http://ip/api/getAllUsers', {params})`

But when I try to make *.env* variables or global :
`fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_IP + '/api/getAllUsers', {params})`

It doesn't work and I don't understand why. I restart my serv, when I log *REACT_APP_IP* it's the good value.

I use this fetch in a functional component in REACT JS in the UseEffect function. I test my routes with Postman and they work fine.

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you forgot ```http://``` on your ```REACT_APP_IP``` ?

Comment: Nop in my *.env* I put this : `REACT_APP_IP=http://MY_IP:7070`

Answer (score 0):

var baseUrl = "put/url/here";

fetch(baseUrl, {params})

Comment: I tried this too. 

`var url = process.env.REACT_APP_IP + '/api/category/getAllCategories'
            fetch(url, {params})`

No responses